# Displaying the 'time ago' for recent activity within a post/custom post type?

Tags: post-meta

How to get the 'freshness' of a post? (when it was last updated or commented and by who?)

> e.g. 48 days / admin (avatar).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this within the Loop:

```
<p>Last modified on the: <?php the_modified_date(); ?>. by: <?php the_author(); ?></p>
```

Comment: I think that function just shows the date the post was modified, it doesn't include users who replied to the post.

Comment: Even so, it still covers the last update time, so it answers half your question.

Comment: @Mark Duncan OK, too bad I can't vote up.